# How can I filter an error message in a user friendly way without creating a custom string in Android?

Tags: java, android, regex, exception, android-alertdialog

I recently created an AlertDialog to inform users that and error has occurred. In the catch block I set the exception message as follows:

```
try {
// Do stuff
} catch (Exception e) {
        mAlertDialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
}
```

This works perfectly fine and the message I see in my AlertDialog is as follows:

```
Read error: ssl=0xb832f3f0: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
```

Is there a way to remove the text so that the error reads as follows:

```
I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
```

I know you can use

```
e.getMessage().substring()
e.getMessage().startsWith()
```

and what not, but I would really like it to report any type of error that might occur, in a user friendly formate. Maybe using regex? Which I don't have much experience with. I would really appreciate a push in the right direction. All tips, hints, incites and help are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm just wondering *what kind of users* you have in mind? Many people would rather have a message like "This app encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for any inconvenience caused." And, if you are still able to do that: "Do you want to give us some feedback?" Then you could send the tech stuff as well as the user's comment, much like app crashes are handled by android.

Comment: The users are internal employees, some of which are IT experts and designers. I just don't want the whole text blocking up the AlertDialog. It needs to be nice and neat. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `replaceFirst`.

```
mAlertDialog.setMessage(e.getMessage().replaceFirst(".*:\\s*", ""));
```

This would match and replace all the characters upto the last colon with empty string.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hB5uX8/1)